# API created for Flask app is extremely slow

Tags: python, flask

I am creating an app to monitor schoolbus arrivals for my school. For this, I have created a simple flask webapp, with an admin page used by admins to input buses that have arrived:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template
import sys

app = Flask(__name__)

original_busdata = {
    "present": [],
    "absent": [i for i in range(1, 32)] # all buses not here to start with
}

busdata = original_busdata

@app.route("/busdata", methods=["GET"])
def transfer_data():
    global busdata
    return jsonify(busdata)

@app.route("/admin", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def template():
    global busdata
    present = []
    absent = []
    # When a checkbox is checked from the
    # admin page, adjust
    # busdata correspondingly
    if request.method == "POST":
        for i in range(1, 32):
            if f"bus-{i}" in request.form:
                present.append(i)
            else:
                absent.append(i)
        busdata["present"] = present
        busdata["absent"] = absent
    # Assemble checkbox data from busdata
    checkbox_data = {}
    for bus in busdata["present"]:
        checkbox_data[bus] = True
    for bus in busdata["absent"]:
        checkbox_data[bus] = False
    # Sort checkbox data so it is in the right order
    checkbox_data = dict(sorted(checkbox_data.items()))
    return render_template("admin.html", busdata=busdata, checkbox_data=checkbox_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

With `admin.html` template:

```html
<div class="page-container">
    <section id="bus-card-container">
        <h2>Buses currently present</h2>
        <div class="bus-list">
            {% for i in busdata["present"] %}
                <span class="bus-present">Bus {{ i }}</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <h2>Buses not here</h2>
        <div class="bus-list">
            {% for i in busdata["absent"] %}
                <span class="bus-absent">Bus {{ i }}</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="admin-panel">
        <button id="clear-all">Clear all buses</button>
        <button id="check-all">Check all buses</button>
        <form id="bus-form" method="post">
        {% for bus in checkbox_data %}
            <div>
                {% if checkbox_data[bus] is sameas true %}
                <input type="checkbox" name="bus-{{ bus }}" id="bus-{{ bus }}" checked>
                {% else %}
                <input type="checkbox" name="bus-{{ bus }}" id="bus-{{ bus }}">
                {% endif %}
                <label for="bus-{{ i }}">Bus {{ bus }}</label>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" id="submit-btn">
        </form>
    </section>
</div>
```

A working example of the admin page can be found at https://three-fifteen-app.vercel.app/admin.

My issue is with the busdata API I defined in the `busdata/` route. Whenever the admin updates `busdata`, it takes forever for the changes made to reflect in the API:

[image: API bug error]

*Notice how the admin shows 3 buses are present on the right, while the busdata API does not reflect this change yet*

And I need the API to be fast enough as my client-side frontend for the app is entirely built around this API. Please let me know what tweaks I can make to my code to resolve this issue.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. When I run your code locally, the "Buses current present" section updates immediately when I press the "Submit" button, and this also seems to be reflected in the `/busdata` endpoint.

Comment: @larsks Perhaps this is an issue with vercel which I'm deploying this on? Because on vercel, it takes quite a while for `/busdata` to update